# Getting Error: Can not convert from 'object' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following small function:

```
public Image AddImage(Stream stream)
{
    return AddImage(stream as object);
}
```

I always getting the Error `Can not convert from 'object' to 'string'`

`Stream` is type of `System.IO.Stream`

Whats wrong? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is there another `AddImage` overload that takes a `string` parameter?

Comment: What does your AddImage(Object) look like?

Comment: Are there other overloads of `AddImage`? If so, please show them.

Comment: @KyorCode, I think he has an overload AddImage(Object obj)

Comment: Paks - you need to show more of your code in order to get sensible suggestions. Best would be to provide a code for a minimal console app which reproduces the problem. How many overloads of AddImage have you written?

Comment: @KyorCode: No. If it were, the error message would be different: `Can not convert from 'object' to 'System.IO.Stream'`

Comment: @NasmiSabeer: Most likely, he doesn't. In that case there wouldn't have been any compiler error.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a full stack trace too which would highlight (to us and you) whether the error is really generated in this method (whcih as many have commented it almost certainly isn't).

Comment: He didn't mention anywhere it's a compiler error

Comment: You could try `return AddImage(((FileStream)stream).Name);`. If that is what you need.

Comment: What about the third function ? AddImage(filename as object, contentType);

Comment: Now I think we also need an explanation of what you expect the problematic method to do. The problem is probably you have no suitable overload for `AddImage(object)` but its not obvious what you are wanting to do when given a stream...

Comment: What ever the value of contentType is you change it at the first line ???  contentType = "image/jpeg";

Answer (score 1):

From your update to the question you have two overloads of `AddImage`. One which takes a `Stream` and one which takes a `string`.

You're attempting to call `AddImage(object)` but there is no matching overload. 
The compiler is telling you that you can't send an object to `AddImage(string blah)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create only one function

```
public Image AddImage(Stream stream, string filename)
    {
        string contentType = "";
        Image image; 

        // The extension this file has will be taken to be its format.
        switch (Path.GetExtension(filename))
        {
            case ".tiff": contentType = "image/tif"; break;
            case ".tif": contentType = "image/tif"; break;
            case ".png": contentType = "image/png"; break;
            case ".bmp": contentType = "image/png"; break;
            case ".gif": contentType = "image/gif"; break;
            case ".jpg": contentType = "image/jpg"; break;
            case ".jpeg": contentType = "image/jpeg"; break;
            default: contentType = "image/jpg"; break;
        }

        //What you do in the third function;

       return image;
    }
```